# Error importing tensorflow : type object 'TypeSpecProto' has no attribute 'NDARRAY_SPEC'

Tags: tensorflow

(Windows 10)
I'm trying to import tensorflow in VS Code.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import tensorflow as tf

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

I get this error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 5 import pandas as pd
> 6
> ----> 7 import tensorflow as tf
> 8
> 9 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py
> in 
> 39 import sys as _sys
> 40
> ---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
> 42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
> 43
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init*_.py
> in 
> 46 from tensorflow.python import data
> 47 from tensorflow.python import distribute
> ---> 48 from tensorflow.python import keras
> 49 from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column_lib as feature_column
> 50 from tensorflow.python.layers import layers
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras_*init*_.py
> in 
> 25
> 26 # See b/110718070#comment18 for more details about this import.
> ---> 27 from tensorflow.python.keras import models
> 28
> 29 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer import Input
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\models.py
> in 
> 21
> 22 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
> ---> 23 from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
> 24 from tensorflow.python.keras import metrics as metrics_module
> 25 from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizer_v1
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py
> in 
> 36 from tensorflow.python import tf2
> 37 from tensorflow.python.client import session as session_module
> ---> 38 from tensorflow.python.distribute import distribute_coordinator as dc
> 39 from tensorflow.python.distribute import distribute_coordinator_context as dc_context
> 40 from tensorflow.python.distribute import distribution_strategy_context
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_coordinator.py
> in 
> 31 from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging
> 32 from tensorflow.python.training import coordinator
> ---> 33 from tensorflow.python.training import monitored_session
> 34 from tensorflow.python.training import server_lib
> 35
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py
> in 
> 44 from tensorflow.python.training import session_run_hook
> 45 from tensorflow.python.training.tracking import graph_view
> ---> 46 from tensorflow.python.training.tracking import util as trackable_util
> 47 from tensorflow.python.util import function_utils
> 48 from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import tf_export
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\util.py
> in 
> 44 from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
> 45 from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging
> ---> 46 from tensorflow.python.saved_model import utils_impl
> 47 from tensorflow.python.training import checkpoint_management
> 48 from tensorflow.python.training import py_checkpoint_reader
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\utils_impl.py
> in 
> 32 from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
> 33 from tensorflow.python.saved_model import constants
> ---> 34 from tensorflow.python.saved_model import nested_structure_coder
> 35 from tensorflow.python.util import compat
> 36 from tensorflow.python.util import deprecation
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\nested_structure_coder.py
> in 
> 493
> 494
> --> 495 class _TypeSpecCodec(object):
> 496   """Codec for `tf.TypeSpec`."""
> 497
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\nested_structure_coder.py
> in _TypeSpecCodec()
> 518       struct_pb2.TypeSpecProto.ROW_PARTITION_SPEC:
> 519           row_partition.RowPartitionSpec,
> --> 520       struct_pb2.TypeSpecProto.NDARRAY_SPEC:
> 521           np_arrays.NdarraySpec,
> 522   }
>
> AttributeError: type object 'TypeSpecProto' has no attribute
> 'NDARRAY_SPEC'

Comment: Can you let us know, what is version of Tensorflow?